# htaccess redirect with query string fails

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Trying to redirect a URL with a query string to a subdomain, and can't get it to work.

The goal is to make `www.example.com/services/json?method=views.get` become `old.example.com/services/json?method=views.get`

I have in the `.htaccess` file:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^www\.example\.com/services/json$ http://old.example.com/services/json$1`

In Chrome, it just stays at the www domain.

In Firefox, it fails once, saying "*Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.*" But if I hit Try Again, it goes to the subdomain just fine.

This is infuriating, and any help is appreciated. I've tried several different patterns.

Thanks!

Also, there are double quotes in the query string. Is it possible to keep them without them becoming encoded to `%2522`?

Comment: The `$1` should not be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.  Here is what I put to get it working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^services/json(.*)$ http://old.example.com/services/json$1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

Everything works perfectly now.

The NE tag at the end of the rule keeps the double quotes in the query string, as needed, and doesn't encode them.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://old.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Modified it to do what I needed to:

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com/services/json$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://old.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

And it doesn't work.  It just stays on the www domain. So it doesn't work, seems not to affect anything.